# Subdomain routing laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain

Please help, subdomains created with code

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{link}.myapp.com'), function(){
Route::get('/{link}', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

when I type in the browser with link.myapp.com, which looks like the following
[image]

This website has been hosted not on localhost anymore. please help me !!

Comment: Please make sure that you do have wildcard record cname within DNS as "*.myapp.com".

Comment: yes I have that, actually myapp.com is not a real domain, that's just my example

Comment: Check here - https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/boygirl.mengundangkamu.com, if you have wildcard cname record then you should get correct IP within whatsmydns.

Comment: how to get the correct IP?

Comment: For the correct IP, Check your DNS settings and make sure to have A with asterisk(*) - https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=hfayW7LJNIrfvgS11KDQCA&q=a+record+for+all+subdomains